# GPT option is not available in Rufus

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, uefi, gpt, rufus

I am trying to install Windows 7 x64 via USB stick but the option of GPT partition scheme isn't there!

I have only MBR option. I am using Windows XP SP3 cause it's the only one available for setup the USB stick.

[image: Rufus in XP SP3]

Comment: I'm _guessing_ it's because XP itself does not support GPT... But, what do you need GPT on a USB stick for, anyway? UEFI does not require it.

Comment: i need to install win 7 or 8 on hp laptop its HDD is GPT scheme so..what am i missing

Comment: But the installation disk doesn't have to be GPT for that. You'll need to boot in UEFI mode, but the install disk can use MBR just fine, as far as I know. So try "MBR scheme for UEFI".

Comment: Rufus author here. Indeed, the issue is that XP doesn't support GPT at all (so even if Rufus was to partition your drive as GPT, you would no longer be able to mount it in Windows). That's precisely why you have "MBR for UEFI" in the dropdown. It will work exactly the same as if you used "GPT for UEFI", as this creates a drive that can only be booted through UEFI.

Comment: Well Akeo doesn't XP 64 bit support GPT? :)
Just kidding! Everybody was using XP 32 bit anyway.
Thank you for being so kind as to deliver support on this platform. I love your tool - thank you for writing it. While other tools ask to remove and reinsert the USB stick after having it prepared you do it in software. That is smarter and convenient. And Rufus is fast like hell.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot boot Windows XP via GPT. GPT disks are supported only by Windows XP 64-Bit Edition.

More generally, only the 64-bit versions of Windows Vista, 7, and 8 support UEFI booting on x86-64 systems; earlier versions and 32-bit versions of the OS can only install or boot in BIOS mode.

**32-bit Windows versions earlier than Vista cannot access GPT partitions. Therefore, you cannot create them either.** It is illogical to attempt that. GPT is used to overcome the 2TB disk size limit, which still applies to boot disks on all 32-bit Windows-based systems.

If you really want to experiment, you can use a 3rd party loader (Like Paragon's GPT loader) that enables GPT emulation via a driver.

Comment: He doesn't want to boot XP though. He wants to create a USB drive with GPT (and Windows 7 Setup) on it.

Comment: I have updated the answer. No difference, it is still not supported.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s really wrong now. While Windows XP cannot access GPT at all, starting from Vista (or Server 2003 SP 1 == XP x64) you can access GPT all you want, even on 32-bit versions. MBR or GPT are also not related to the CPU architecture at all. You can of course access GPT and disks larger than 2 TiB on a 32-bit CPU. Indeed, you don’t even need UEFI to boot from GPT disks. That’s a Windows limitation.

Comment: I didn't say it's a CPU limitation. It's a windows 32-bit one.

Comment: Yeah, no. I’ve taken the liberty to try and remove the ambiguity from your answer while staying true to the original content as much as possible.